# Is there anything like Vaadin for .net?

Tags: .net, vaadin

Sorry for asking such a basic question, I have just come across Vaadin, it looks like a interesting way of creating web applications.    I am very out of date of what the state of the art is these days, having last worked on web applications with classic ASP.NET, but do know about ASP.MVC.

As my background is C# and .NET I mostly get to work on systems that have a very large code base in C#, so just jumping ship to Java is not a good option.

Comment: The Vaadin group just [announced their .net product](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-switching-to-c-1?vaadin.net) this week. On the 1st. ;-)

Comment: @BasilBourque,  That page says "This was an April fools joke. "

Comment: Yes, I know. You must missed the winking emoticon at the end of my comment. No Vaadin for .Net as Vaadin and [GWT](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit). both are built on Java.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, and apparently [Wikipedia's knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit#Other_frameworks), there are no C# GWT-based frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, I see GWT as being an implementation detail of Vaadin.    I am more after “server side code with rich and interactive user experience, the tookkit used on the client side is not important to me, provided I don’t need to access it directly.

Comment: @IanRingrose In Vaadin 6 and earlier, the product was indeed architected with a interface delivery layer so that other technologies instead of [GWT](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) might be plugged-in to deliver the user experience, such as Swing or Cocoa. No one ever stepped up to perform that development work. With Vaadin 7 the team declared that the Web had won the user interface wars. They removed that layer.

Answer (score 4):

I would say Microsoft's Blazor framework (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) is the equivalent for C#/.NET.

Answer (score 1):

CSHTML5 seems to be an app in a similar vein: http://www.cshtml5.com/

According to their website: "Create HTML5 apps using only C# and XAML with Visual Studio"